# Discord.Net How to list all commands in a group

Tags: discord, discord.net

```
    <Group("math")>
Public Class cmd_math
    Inherits ModuleBase

#Region "Add"

    <Command("add")>
    Public Async Function cmdAdd(ByVal num1 As Integer, <Remainder> ByVal num2 As Integer) As Task

        Dim sum = num1 + num2
        Dim user = Context.User
        Dim channel = Context.Channel

        Await channel.SendMessageAsync($"{user.Mention} the sum of the two specified numbers are {sum}")

    End Function

#End Region

#Region "Subtract"

    <Command("sub")>
    Public Async Function cmdSub(ByVal num1 As Integer, <Remainder> ByVal num2 As Integer) As Task

        Dim sum = num1 - num2
        Dim user = Context.User
        Dim channel = Context.Channel

        Await channel.SendMessageAsync($"{user.Mention} the sum of the two specified numbers are {sum}")

    End Function

#End Region

#Region "Multiply"

    <Command("multi")>
    Public Async Function cmdMulti(ByVal num1 As Integer, <Remainder> ByVal num2 As Integer) As Task

        Dim sum = num1 * num2
        Dim user = Context.User
        Dim channel = Context.Channel

        Await channel.SendMessageAsync($"{user.Mention} the sum of the two specified numbers are {sum}")

    End Function

#End Region

#Region "Divide"

    <Command("divide")>
    Public Async Function cmdDivide(ByVal num1 As Integer, <Remainder> ByVal num2 As Integer) As Task

        Dim sum = num1 / num2
        Dim user = Context.User
        Dim channel = Context.Channel

        Await channel.SendMessageAsync($"{user.Mention} the sum of the two specified numbers are {sum}")

    End Function

#End Region

End Class
```

How would I go about creating a command lets say called 'list' which would then send an embed with the list of commands automatically without having to write the embed and fill it in automatically? If it can't be done within an embed using a regular image is fine. I'm pretty sure it's going to use a for loop for that but after that, I don't know how to take it on.

Comment: The `CommandService` has all the information you need to do what you desire. Simply inject it into you module via dependency injection and look at it's various properties. You can get all modules, sub modules, commands within those modules etc.

Comment: I'm not sure where to start..

Comment: I'm really new when it comes to coding and I have no clue how to do inject or where to really start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your program you would probably have something like

```vb
Dim collection As New ServiceCollection()
collection.AddSingleton(DiscordSocketClient())
```

or however you add your client to your `IserviceProvider`
You `ServiceProvider` is what is used for dependency injection. To inject the command service you would need to add it to the `ServiceCollection`

```vb
collection.AddSingleton(New CommandService())
```

To inject it into your command module, simply add an argument to your constructor

```vb
Public Class YourCommandModule
    Inherits ModuleBase(Of SocketCommandContext)

    Private ReadOnly Property Commands As CommandService

    Public Sub New(commands As CommandService)
        Me.Commands = commands
    End Sub
```

Then you can create your help command within that class, which now has access to the `CommandService`

```vb
    <Command("Help")>
    Public Async Function Help() As Task
        'Create your embed builder 
        '...

        'You can access all module classes using `CommandService.Modules`
        For Each moduleData As ModuleInfo In Commands.Modules
            Dim cmds As List(CommandInfo) = moduleData.Commands 'this gives a list of all commands in this class 
            'you can now do something with that list of commands 
            'add each one to a embed field for example
        Next
    End Function
```

You can look at the different things you have access to via ModuleInfo and CommandInfo

Comment: thanks for the help. I didn't code the bot from scratch, I watched a video that was a couple of years old so not sure where to execute any of this code. Looked into my command handler https://hastebin.com/xikonuyire.properties  which seem to be the only spot where it mentions service provider but can't get it all together. Thanks for the help.